# Factoring $x^5 + x + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> Factor. $\displaystyle x^5 + x + 1$.

I'm trying my hand on these types of expressions. In the book, it mentions that for these types you should rewrite the $x$ term such as $2x-x$. But I don't know how to make any use of this technique.

What is this type of factoring called by the way?

Comment: I have no idea what the $2x-x$ is supposed to do for you. But you can get some mileage out of adding and subtracting $x^2$, that is, writing $(x^5-x^2)+(x^2+x+1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gerry suggests, we can add and subtract $\;+ x^2 - x^2 = 0 $ without changing the expression:

$$\begin{align} x^5 + x + 1 & = (x^5-x^2)+(x^2+x+1)\\ \\ & = x^2(x^3 - 1) + (x^2 + x + 1) \\ \\ & = x^2(x-1)\color{blue}{\bf (x^2 + x + 1)} + \color{blue}{\bf (x^2 + x + 1)}\end{align}$$

Now factor out the common factor...which gives us $$\Big(x^2(x-1) + 1\Big)(x^2 + x + 1) = (x^3 - x^2 + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$$

Comment: I got $(x^2+x+1)(x^2(x-1)+1) = (x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)$

How do I spot that fact that I should add and subtract $x^2$? Also I didn't know that $(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, are there any main identities like these that I should be aware of?

thanks

Comment: How to spot? It usually is a matter of practice! Also, whenever you encounter $x^n - 1$, you should check $x - 1$ as a factor!

Comment: You should *definitely* be aware that $$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1$$ There's a similar identity for $x^n+1$, though it only works when $n$ is odd --- you might try to work it out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How do I use this when $n=2$? I tried: $x^2 -1 = (x-1)(x^1+x^0+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+...+x+1) = (x-1)(2x+2+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+x^{-3}+...)$

Is the $x^{-1}+x^{-2}+...$ a sum to infinity with $a = x^{-1}$ and $r=x^{-1}$?

Comment: @user90771: I agree with Amy in her first comment. It will be disclosed to you just by practicing. If $n=2$, then $$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$.

Comment: @BabakS. I substituted n=2 into the equation posted above and got $x^2-1 = (x-1)(2(x+1) + \frac{1}{x-1}) = 2(x-1)(x+1)+1$ where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @user90771: What is the last term of the identity Gerry posted? Isn't it $1$?? So we have to go forward putting $n=k$ into the powers **till** you get this number. I mean $1$. So after $x^0$ we have nothing just a $)$. ;-)

Comment: @BabakS. hey i didnt understand why we need to put n = k?
when we put n = 2, why do the terms after the first 2 terms cancel?

Comment: @user90771: I wanted to make a certain power so I got $n=k$. Yes we have $n=2$. Note that we are working with polynomials. What are the powers of a polynomial $p(x)$?

Comment: @BabakS. $p(x) = 1 + ax + bx^2+cx^3..$?

Comment: @user90771: Nope! it is $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1$

Comment: @BabakS. so for a quadratic, n = 2? so we have $$p(x) = x^1 + x^0 + x^{-1} + x^{-2) + ... + x + 1$$?

Comment: @user90771 No, for n = 2 , we have $x^2 - 1 = (x - 1)(p(x))$ where $p(x) = x^{2-1} + x^{2-2} = x + 1$. $p(x)$ stops with the term with the zero the: the nth term. S$x^{n - n} = x^0 = 1$

Comment: For $n = 3$ we have $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^{3-1} + x^{3-2} + x^{3-3}) = (x -1)(x^2 + x + 1)$. For $n = 4$ we have $x^4 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{4-1} + x^{4-2} + x^{4-3} + x^{4-4}) = (x - 1)(x^3 + x^2+x + 1)...$

Comment: @amWhy thanks, if a quadratic has the highest power of 2, why does n = 3 for a quadratic? Is there a derivation of this formula which I could read upon?
thanks

Comment: I was showing that $x^n - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{n - 1} + \cdots x^{n - n}$, regardless of whether $n = 2, 3, 4, \cdots$, that's all.

Comment: @amWhy done thanks, do you mind telling me the name of this formula or how it's derived? I would like to read about it

Comment: Search for "difference of powers". For odd $n$, we also have "sum of powers", e.g., [this link.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Sum_and_difference_of_powers). You'll see a generalized formula for $(x^n - y^n)$. What we've been discussing here is a specific case for $y = 1$.

Comment: It's also the sum of a geometric sequence, another formula you should know. $$\sum_0^mar^k={a(r^{m+1}-1)\over r-1}$$ Replace $a$ with 1, $r$ with $x$, and $m$ with $n-1$, and voila!

Answer (score 4):

You can verify that both primitive $3$rd roots of unity are roots of this equation, since $5$ is $2$ mod $3$. This means the corresponding cyclotomic polynomial, $x^2+x+1$, divides $x^5+x+1$, and you can do polynomial division to find the other factor.

The answer is $(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)$.

Comment: This is fine --- if OP knows what a "primitive 3rd root of unity" is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I admit this is probably a useless answer. I'm only posting it because one of my physics professors once used this polynomial as a example of a 5th degree equation that could not be solved in radicals. (It was in a lecture on perturbation theory, and the roots of the polynomial were then found numerically using a perturbation method.) I didn't catch his mistake until after the lecture, but I've been on the lookout for this polynomial ever since.